# Adult X-Men fanfic involving a mind controller who seduces all of the females in the Marvel comics continuity

Tags: story-identification, marvel, fan-fiction

I think I read it in early college, so around 2000, online,  in English, maybe on a fanfic site. It was a fairly decent length, maybe 50-60 pages, and the scenes were fairly varied. The basic concept is pretty much exactly as noted above. The protagonist is a young male (teenager to young adult) who apparently has the mutant power to mind control others, and he decides to use it to sleep with all of the female Marvel heroines one by one. I think there was some conceit going on where he gained more power the more of them he was able to control/convert into his slaves. The only one that has stuck with me was Psylocke, who invoked some sort of "secret Asian sex technique" that involves him managing to ejaculate and urinate at the same time. Said technique had "gold" or "golden" in it. I think that part of his taking over Sue Storm involved setting [Malice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malice_(comics)#Malice_(Marauder)) free complete with the choker appearing (which yes, mixes two of the villains named Malice). I think there may have been some bit where he also gained control over Mr. Fantastic and there was a joke about "being able to stretch any part of his body" in a stereotypical sex manner.

The only other detail that I remember clearly is that it later turns out that the protagonist's mentally disabled  (maybe only seemingly, because the power kept her from focusing?) sister was the one with the mind control power. I vaguely remember that there was a scene (flashback?) halfway or two-thirds through the story where she was in a towel and it fell off, and I think that either precipitated the protagonist's mind control, or revealed to him that she was the one with the power all along.

Comment: I do not know whether mind control can be described as a form of *seduction*. Seduction is buying someone chocolates, striking a sexy pose, or saying flattering things to them. Mind control is more like drugging someone (which is classified as rape in the United States).

Comment: @Adamant I was phrasing the title more delicately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a certain mind control site is where I first read it but in the early 2000's that site pulled all of the comic based stories because Marvel put pressure for them to remove it however.

*[Submission Agenda](https://www.dangerbabecentral.com/xpage/stories/author.php?author=Pegasus&letter=p)* by Pegasus777

It also has been turn into a comic but you will find both versions.  Sorry it took so many years to get your answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Instead of telling us to Google it, you should include the relevant links and summaries of them.  You might want to read [answer].

Comment: Because of some of the links could be of issue i felt that it would be more appropriate to not link to those sites but by providing the name of story and author it will allow them to  choose the site that they are willing to deal with but thank you

Comment: I am adding an additional bounty on this to give you more points, because I have been looking for this in one form or another for some time.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Congratulations. That should give you enough points that you will be able to use the chat and comment functions on all posts, as well as, I think, enough that you get that benefit on any other Stack Exchange sites you join.